# Block all user-agents by htaccess except one

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

I have a htaccess rewrite rule code which works on Apache but not on litespeed.

```
<Files "bg.js">
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*autoit.* search_robot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=search_robot
</Files>
```

I want to block all useragents except those that are a case insensitive match to `autoit`.

How do I get the rewrite rule to work on litespeed?

Comment: You can use my rewrite rules for bad User-Agents and Referrers here - https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/apache-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker/tree/master/OpenLitespeed_htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, LiteSpeed does not support `SetEnvIf*` directives in `.htaccess` files. As an alternative, you'll need to use `mod_rewrite`:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

# Check that the request is for /bg.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bg.js

# Check that the request matches an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

# Check that the user agent does not contain autoit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !autoit

# If all conditions above are met, then deny access to this request
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```